# Error:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'org.gradle.model.ModelMap<org.gradle.language.base.FunctionalSourceSet>'

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Using *classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-rc1'* for ndk application for Android studio i'm having problem implementing gradle script for my library but when using it for an application it's working

```
    /*test ndk*/
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        //compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        //buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "sample.alvin.mylibrary"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 4
            versionName "1.0.1"
        }




        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources true
                useProguard true
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.release")
            }
        }

        sources{
            main{
                jniLibs.srcDirs 'libs'
                jni.srcDirs = []
            }
        }




    }


    android.signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            //keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            //keyPassword STORE_PASSWORD
            //storeFile file(STORE_FILE)
            //storePassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

 /*   android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'libs'
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }*/

/*    android.ndk {
        moduleName "android-native"
        ldLibs.addAll(['log'])
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
        platformVersion 15
        stl 'gnustl_shared'
    }*/



}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
}
```

I also see [this problem also](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205672). Does anyone implemented the ndk implementation for an module/library, how to do it?

Comment: You should edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: seems quite specific to me.